# Error installing Laravel 5.1 on DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, laravel-5.1

I've the basic droplet from DigitalOcean.

First I installed `composer` as follows:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

and then I tried to install Laravel as follows:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Then I got the following Error:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
    Loading from cache

Created project in /var/www/html/laravel
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Loading from cache
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 974, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(974): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(784): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(745): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(675): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 974

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 974, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(974): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(784): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(745): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(675): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 974
```

How can I solve this problem? Tired of searching for different solutions online and didnt work anything.

Comment: 512 MB RAM, 1 TB Bandwidth, 20 GB Disk

Comment: Look at @Dave Alvarez's answer. It's the problem with the memory. I'm using 1 GB Digital Ocean and it works fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's because of a lack of memory. You need to set up a swap file so that composer can do it's thing:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k

mkswap /swapfile

swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: I'm getting this erro: `dd: unrecognized operand ‘count’`

Comment: No idea why it would give that error, but you can go here to see alternative ways of creating swap files:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04